# Getting The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet error

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, mvvm-light

I am using silverlight mvvm light framework. when I was trying to delete entity I got The specified entity is not contained in this EntitySet. error but in my Database that entity is already there.

```
   context.FormSection.Remove(formSection);
```

In this code I am getting error.

This is my code where I am doing delete operation

```
   public void DeleteSectionQuestion(Form currentForm,CustomSectionTree selectedSectionQuestion, DeleteDelegate callback)
    {
        FormSection fs = new FormSection();

        foreach (Question q in selectedSectionQuestion.Questions)
        {
            fs.FormID = currentForm.FormID;
            fs.SectionID = selectedSectionQuestion.SectionID;
            fs.QuestionID = q.QuestionID;
            context.FormSections.Remove(fs);
        }

        SubmitOperation so = context.SubmitChanges();
        so.Completed += (s, args) =>
        {
            if (so.HasError)
            {
                so.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                callback.Invoke(false, so.Error);
            }
            else
                callback.Invoke(true, null);
        };
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide code, stack trace...etc. or we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the following piece of your code:

```
FormSection fs = new FormSection();

foreach (Question q in selectedSectionQuestion.Questions)
{
    fs.FormID = currentForm.FormID;
    fs.SectionID = selectedSectionQuestion.SectionID;
    fs.QuestionID = q.QuestionID;
    context.FormSections.Remove(fs);
}
```

You are creating a new instance of `FormSection`, and then try to delete it multiple times. `Entities`/`EntitySet` don't work that way: **the context tracks which entities you retrieved from the database**. It means that if you try to remove an entity that is not an instance of an entity that came from the database, it is **unknown for the context**.

You should have a list of queried `FormSections` in your viewmodel, you should delete instances of `FormSection` that come from this list so they are known by the context.